# Como personalizar mensagem de erro do java.io.IOException no Android?

Tags: java, android

Quando o Android faz uma conexão externa e esta url não está disponível o mesmo retorna um erro.

Como personalizar um erro como no exemplo abaixo:

```
java.io.IOException: Error response: 401 Service Unavailable
```

para algo do tipo:

```
Erro: Serviço não dospinível
```

Espero ter sido claro na pergunta.

Comment: Como esta mensagem esta sendo exibida na tela? Poderia postar um trecho do código em que exibe ela?

Comment: O erro é no momento da conexão do aacencoder. Quando o streaming não está disponível o erro citado acima aparece na tela. multiPlayer.playAsync("http://url-do-streaming:8000"); Meu código é semelhante a este: https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/source/browse/trunk/player/src/com/spoledge/aacplay/AACPlayerActivity.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro já está sendo personalizado pela biblioteca/método que está produzindo a `IOException`. Nesse caso a solução seria capturar essa *exception* em um bloco `catch()` e lançar uma nova `IOException` com o texto customizado. Se você quiser customizar esse texto somente quando a `IOException` original contiver exatamente o texto *"Error response: 401 Service Unavailable"* terá que fazer uma comparação dessa string com a que é retornada por `exception.getMessage()` (usando `equals()`).

Por exemplo:

```
try {
    ...
    player.playAsync(url);
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    if ("Error response: 401 Service Unavailable".equals(e.getMessage()) {
        throw new IOException("Erro: Serviço não disponível");
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```